# How can I left shift an array list by 2 post?

Tags: java

For example, there is an arraylist: 40 8 6 3 7 5 2, and I want to left shift them by 2 post. And then expected output is 6 3 7 5 2. I have wrote the following code, but it generate nothing

Code:
    import java.util.ArrayList;

```
class ArrayLinearListRev extends ArrayLinearList{
public ArrayList<Integer> leftSh(int post, ArrayList<Integer> 
alist2)
{
   ArrayList<Integer> LeftshifedList = new ArrayList<Integer    
();
   for (int i = alist2.size(); i <= post; i++)
   {
       LeftshifedList.remove(alist2.get(i));
   }

   return LeftshifedList;

 }

 public void printElements(ArrayList<Integer> alist2)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < alist2.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(alist2.get(i) + " ");
    }
 }
 }

public class ArrayLinearListFun  {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayLinearListRev obj = new ArrayLinearListRev();
    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    x.add(0, new Integer(2));
    x.add(1, new Integer(5));
    x.add(2, new Integer(7));
    x.add(3, new Integer(3));
    x.add(4, new Integer(6));
    x.add(5, new Integer(8));
    x.add(6, new Integer(40));
    System.out.print("The list is: ");
    obj.printElements(x);
    x=obj.leftSh(2, x);
    System.out.print("\nThe list is: ");
    obj.printElements(x);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `leftSh` method returns an empty `List`. Assuming you don't want your method modify the original `List`, you should initialize `LeftshifedList` to be a copy of the original `List`.

You simply need to remove the element at index `0` and repeat `post` times.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> leftSh(int post, ArrayList<Integer> alist2)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> LeftshifedList = new ArrayList<>(alist2); // create a copy of input List
    for (int i = 1; i <= post; i++) { // remove the first post elements
        LeftshifedList.remove(0); 
    }
    return LeftshifedList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first two elements.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> leftSh(int post, ArrayList<Integer>  alist2) {

  alist2.remove(0);
  alist2.remove(0);
  return alist2;
}
```

Comment: This only produces the desired output if `post == 2`.